# Can't Find My Include

Tags: ros, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I have two packages: OpenRAVEROSInterp and myTestROS.

OpenRAVEROSInterp is a little package I developed which connects OpenRAVE and ROS.  It works well and uses a file named ROSRobot.h which contains subscriptions/services to interact with robots in OpenRAVE.  It is stored in

```
rospackages/OpenRAVEROSInterp/include/OpenRAVEROSInterp/ROSRobot.h
```

My other package myTestROS is attempting to use ROSRobot.h (just for fun).  It's manifest.xml  has

When I run rosmake, I get...

```
 ...workspace/rospackages/myTestROS/src/TestClass.cpp:36:40: error: OpenRAVEROSInterp/ROSRobot.h: No such file or directory
```

Where line 36 is:

```
#include <OpenRAVEROSInterp/ROSRobot.h>
```

Could anyone off any suggestions?  Thank you.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11951/can%27t-find-my-include/) by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 296 on 2011-11-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need to set some `export` tags in your package's `manifest.xml`. [See the wikipage on manifests.](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Manifest)

---

Originally posted by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) with karma: 4119 on 2011-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2011-11-16**:
@joq Yes I can roscd to it.  @tfoote Interesting, I thought he meant I had to add export flags to myTestROS.  I am interested as to why this is so, I figured the rosmake system would be able to handle includes from other packages.  I will examine the wiki page.  Thank you all for your patience!

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-11-15**:
@Constantin S This works for tf because it uses the export tags like @Mac said.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-11-15**:
Is OpenRAVEROSInterp in your $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH? Can you `roscd` to it?

**Comment by [Constantin S](https://answers.ros.org/users/911/constantin-s/) on 2011-11-15**:
How come when you , you can $include<tf/tflistener.h> .  What's the difference with my package?